# Setting variable from within AJAX call?

Tags: jquery

Im sure its something simple, but i cant seem to set variable data from within an AJAX request..

My servlet returns an array of numbers;

```
    int[] array = {1,2,4,5,3,5,3,5};

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(array));
```

The data is passed to jquery, where i am trying to store the json data as an jquery array;

```
    var test2 = [];
    $.post("servlet", { info: data},
                function(data) {
                    alert(data); // this alerts what i want stored...
                    test2.push(3); // testing if i can add 3 to test FAILS
                });
    test2.push(9); //this works
    test2.push(9); //this works
    options.series[0].data = test2;
```

Why can't i push a number onto test from with the ajax call?

The final result i want is to set options.series[0].data equal to the array of data returned by the servlet

Comment: I don't see any variable declaration for `test2`. Is this a typo ?

Comment: Is the `alert(data)` being triggered?

Comment: Duplicate of [all of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+how+to+return+value+from+ajax+call). I'm pretty sure `test2.push(3)` works, how to do you know it does not?

Comment: alert(data); pops up with 1,2,4,5,3,5,3,5 and test.push(3) doesn't get added as i only have to numbers coming through in my chart.. 9 and 9...

Comment: @Lunar: Break down the problem into a reprodicible testcase. I'm sure you'll find that you can't do that without finding the cause on your own.

Comment: Well, you are assigning `test2` to `options.series[0].data` and probably draw the chart before the `success` callback is called, which means that the time you process the data, `3` was not added yet. But it definitely gets added.

Comment: Oh i see, so really i should wait until i generate my chart?

Comment: Yes, you can only show your chart when you have the data. You get the data once the success callback is called, so that's where /when you have to make the call to draw your chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you deciding that the push is "failing"? Keep in mind that the `3` will be added LONG after the `9`s because your AJAX request is asynchronous.

```
var test2 = [];
$.post("servlet", { info: data},
            function(data) {
                alert(data); // this alerts what i want stored...
                test2.push(3); // testing if i can add 3 to test FAILS
                alert(test2)
            });
```

Comment: I moved the chart call inside the ajax request, this worked a treat.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just set your variables within the AJAX like so:

```
function(data){
    options.series[0].data=data;
}
```

However, I would also suggest to use the actual `$.ajax` object, due to the capabilities.

Comment: You're just moving the "problem" to another variable.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the complete ajax() function, with async: false.

```
var test2 = [];
$.ajax({
   url: "servlet",
   async: false,
   type: "post",
   data: { info: data},
   success: function(data) {
                alert(data); // this alerts what i want stored...
                test2.push(3); // testing if i can add 3 to test FAILS
            });
});
```

EDITED: Removed a wrong statement.

Comment: Making synchronous calls is a bad idead in general, as it freezes the browser's UI. And of course you can change a variable with an Ajax call.

Comment: sure he can change that variable, the question is when he's checking it

Comment: Huh? Asynchronous request callbacks magically can't alter variables now?

Comment: @FelixKling: Does it *really* freeze the browser UI, these days? Any more than a standard page load?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Maybe not the whole browser, definitely the page. Depends on how long it takes to receive an answer. If the call is synchronous, then JavaScript is waiting, which means it runs. You can simulate this by having any JavaScript code running for 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: @FelixKling no of course it doesn't freeze the browser, then it wouldn't be A-synchronous. Now this answer AND the comments have misinformation.

Comment: @Sinetheta: Since when is a synchronous request asynchronous?

Comment: @Sinetheta: You probably missed `async: false`.

Comment: @FelixKling: I continue to wonder why that is such a problem for people, in the general case. Sure, sometimes I want to interleave XmlHttpRequests; other times, I don't and the usual page load behaviour (i.e. the "freeze" you speak of) is fine, and I gain a huge increase in code flow simplicity. It depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @Sinetheta: You've been misled by the appalling term "AJAX", which is better known as XmlHttpRequest. You can turn it into synchronous mode, which is what mariogl has done with the `async: false` setting. You should read the documentation. **"AJAX" is not always asynchronous.**

Comment: Dear god, you're right. I apologise @FelixKling I've never even SEEN someone set that flag. That is a horrible idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Page loading and making an synchronous XmlHttpRequests is different. During page load you just wait until the page is there and that's fine because you cannot do anything else anyway. But if a synchronous XmlHttpRequests is made, you cannot interact with the page at all, not even scroll the page. And everything that takes longer than 100ms is noticeable by the user. That's why you should not have any lon running JavaScript computation either, if it takes longer than 100ms, the user will experience some kind of lag.

Comment: @FelixKling: Maybe, in this particular case, the user doesn't want to interact with the page. Maybe the request is _semantically_ synchronous, too. If the user can deal with >100ms when waiting for the page to first load, he/she can damned well deal with it again when waiting for me to change part of it.

Comment: For example, if a user has filled in part of a form, and now we need to retrieve some information from the server before proceeding. I don't _want_ my user to go off and do something else on the same page; they must wait for the retrieval to conclude, or they're going to break the flow of the activity. It's a sequential activity, that happens to have network communication in the middle of it. Though I'm _still_ not convinced that synchronous requests prevent you from even scrolling the page.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, there are edge cases where this is fine, that's why I said it's a bad idea *in general*. Still, making synchronous calls should be the exception or the user should be notified about this. I think we are pretty used to the fact that can interact with the things we see. Having an unresponsive interface is surprising and confusing... but that's not a discussion for the comments :) *edit*: Regarding the form example: In that case I would still to an async request and show a notification that the user should wait. Browsers also have limits on JS execution time.

Comment: @Felix: Again, I have yet to see any proof that it creates an "unresponsive interface" any more than is expected in such circumstances. Seems to be a bit of a mantra to me. Anyway.

Comment: Ok to the downvoting for "you won't be able to change that variable", I was a little confused about scopes and after your comments I got it more clear. I'm not so sure about the opinions on synchronous call. I think it would be more useful for the OP a clarification about consequences on synchronous call, since it would solve his question. He could evaluate if is interested in synchronous or not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Here is a made up example for an synchronous call. I set the time to wait to 5 seconds, you can play around with that. http://jsfiddle.net/UMPkE/ (notice that it is not possible to scroll). That's my last statement for this discussion, it was a good discussion and I see your point :)